# Is it possible to change standard CSS colors in VS CODE?

Tags: css, visual-studio-code

When you type CSS code in VS CODE, it uses Intellisense to suggest a color presets, for example, `black` is equal to `#000`.

---

So, can I change this `black` again, for example, to be `#495057`?

Comment: You could assign something like
const theme = {
  colors: {
     black: '#495057'
  }
}

if you are using css in js
Or if you are using scss you could assign colors using sass variables like so
$color-black: #495057

Comment: @Aquasar its good, but i asked about VS Code.

Comment: @PythonNewbie  - If your question is to change the basic color palette to your custom one for VS code themes then it's not recommended. However, if you want to use those colors anywhere else like in a project or something then it can be done by various methods. For eg, the answer as given below

Comment: why would you want to change the standardized colors when you already have the color you want?  (#495057)

Answer (score 0):

You can use css variables for this.
For example in your css files.

```
:root {
  --main-bg-color: coral;
  --black-color: #495057;
}

#div1 {
  background-color: var(--main-bg-color);
  color: var(--black-color);
}

#div2 {
  background-color: var(--main-bg-color);
  color: var(--black-color);
}
```

You can now use these css variables and throughout your code and assign different shades of black to them